# How we display date in button

Tags: angular

Is this possible to display as shown in image using angular? slider should consist of button with date labeled in it. user should able to slide front and back. date to should be displayed before and after current date.

Example image is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Please add some code you already tried.

Comment: var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
console.log(currentdate)  this prints only next date.. but i want to get all coming dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way if you have an array of dates in your component:

```
dates = [new Date(2020, 0, 31), new Date(2021, 2, 24), new Date()];
```

to use `*ngFor` with a [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
<button *ngFor="let date of dates">
  {{ date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}
</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqp7e6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)